# Nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutDimension>' Swift 3

Tags: swift3, nslayoutconstraint

I recently converted my code to Swift 3.  When setting a constraint I no longer can pass in nil to set a constant value. I've searched similar posts and the documentation and can't seem to find what to do in this case.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [documentation for NSLayoutConstraint](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nslayoutanchor/1500937-constraint) the type of the first argument is not optional. So, you cannot pass `nil`. What you're trying to achieve can be done using the [constraintEqualToConstant](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nslayoutdimension/1500941-constraint) method.